# smarty send query

Tags: php, smarty

in  .php

```
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$value[] = $line;
$value['newvalue'] ='223457';
}
$smarty->assign('view', $value);
```

in .tpl

```
 {section name=i loop=$view}
 {$view[i].newvalue}
 {/section}
```

no output for newvalue.im newbie in smarty

Answer (score 1):

You are kind of close,  maybe...  Anyway this is what you want. Make sure to indent your code so people can read it.

```
$c=0;
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $value[$c] = $line;
   $value[$c]['newvalue'] ='223457';
   $c++;
}
$smarty->assign('view', $value);
```

in .tpl:

```
{foreach item=v from $view}
  {$v.newvalue}
{/foreach}
```